# fuzziness in elastic search search by letter not by word

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, fuzzy

Hey I am trying to make a fuzzy search in Elasticsearch I write this query

```
  "query": {
"match": {
  "NAME": {
    "query": "data"  ,
    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
  }   
}
```

}

but it keeps return the best match on word not the nearest letter
what I need is actually near to google search any idea ?

Comment: can you please explain your use case with the help of an example ?

Comment: @ESCoder i have a long description value's and i am trying to search on part of the value but the first value i get is the best match on word not on best match on letter for example i am searching for bankok and i have "albankok" and "the capital of tankok"
it will return the capital of tankok first